# Pasting array to Excel column produces Run-time error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA programming so forgive the noobie question. I have a very simple code whihc basically puts some 200 000 records into an array. I then want to paste these records into say Column A in Sheet1. However I keep getting "Run-time error 13 Type mismatch". Below is the code.

```
Sub array_testing()

Dim i As Long
Dim MyArray() As String

i = 2

Sheets("Customer Data").Activate

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
ReDim Preserve MyArray(i)
MyArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
i = i + 1
Loop

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can just say myArray() as variant.  and myArray = range("a1:a200000").value, you'd need to say range("a1").value = transpose(... is this to make vertical array horizontal?

Comment: I filled the array with values from one column and want to paste them into another column. So I suppose the array data should be vertical and I want to paste them vertically. Now that you mentioned it I doubt that the . Transpose is what I need but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: `range("b1").value=myarray` then, keep your loop as is, if you are looping to the 1st empty cell though, may be best to find last row, then use `range("b1:b" & lastrow).value=("a1:a" & lastrow).value`

Comment: you need to transpose your data in this way: `....Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)`

Comment: I edited the code as shown above and now I am getting Run-time error 13 Type mismatch again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without loops but still with arrays:

```
'activate sheet if required
'copying to array
Dim arrSource As Variant
arrSource = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Value

'pasting from array
'change sheet index to sheet name
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrSource, 1), 1).Value = arrSource
```

You could also consider using `Range.Copy Destinaton` method.

---

The same result with `Range.Copy destination` looks like this:

```
Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Copy    Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

The line above copies cells and immediately paste them. 
Alternatively you could use separate `Range.Copy` and `Range.PasteSpecial` if required.

Comment: Thank you both Nathan and Jawor. My code works perfectly now

Comment: One more thing though Jawor. Could you please tell me how ca the Range.Copy method be used to paste the array contents?

Comment: Thanks Jawor,
Howeever I want to use the Redim Preserve array and when I fill my array in this way when I try to paste the values after that the code just pastes the 1st value all the way down to the 200 000 th row. Here is the code:

Comment: Sub array_testing2()

Dim i As Long
Dim MyArray() As Variant

i = 2

Sheets("Customer Data").Activate

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
ReDim Preserve MyArray(i)
MyArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
i = i + 1
Loop

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1), 1).Value = MyArray

End Sub

Comment: can you please add your code into your question to improve readability, please...

Comment: Just did, sorry about that.